# How to get FTP file name and folder name?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am writing an update program using C# (Winform) in Visual Studio 2013. I want to download FTP file and folder recursive, because the folder contains my remote update file.

**my cs :**

```
    #region 递归文件夹
    /// <summary>  
    /// 递归下载文件  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="ftpIPAddress">FTP服务器的IP</param>  
    /// <param name="name">需要下载文件路径</param>  
    /// <param name="localPath">保存的本地路径</param>  
    public void downFTP(string ftpIPAddress, string name, string localPath)
    {
        string downloadDir = localPath + name;
        string ftpDir = ftpIPAddress + "/" + name;
        string[] fullname = FTP(ftpDir, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails);
        //判断是否为单个文件   
        if (fullname.Length <= 2)
        {
            string singleFullFileName = fullname[fullname.Length - 1];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(singleFullFileName))
            {
                string FTPFileName = GetFolderNameByFTPDirectoryDetail(singleFullFileName);
                FTPDownloadFile(ftpIPAddress, userName, passWord, localPath, FTPFileName, FTPFileName);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Error("下载FTP文件时，文件名为空，请检查，fullname:" + singleFullFileName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string[] onlyname = FTP(ftpDir, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory);
            if (!Directory.Exists(downloadDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadDir);
            }
            foreach (string names in fullname)
            {
                //判断是否具有文件夹标识<DIR>  
                if (names.Contains("<DIR>"))
                {
                    string olname = names.Split(new string[] { "<DIR>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim();
                    //如果为文件夹,在temp目录下创建相同结构的文件夹
                    string FTPFolderName = GetFolderNameByFTPDirectoryDetail(names);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FTPFolderName))
                    {
                        PreUpdate(FTPFolderName);
                        //如果为文件夹，递归下载
                        downFTP(ftpDir, "//" + olname, downloadDir);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Info("获取到空的文件夹名称");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (string onlynames in onlyname)
                    {
                        if (onlynames == "" || onlynames == " " || names == "")
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (names.Contains(" " + onlynames))
                            {
                                //DownloadFile(downloadDir + "/" + onlynames, ftpAddr + name + "/" + onlynames);
                                FTPDownloadFile(ftpIPAddress, userName, passWord, localPath, onlynames, onlynames);
                                logger.Info("下载文件，下载存储位置：" + downloadDir + ",FTP位置：" + ftpDir);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

And you can see, the function **`FTPDownloadFile`** need the `filename` parameter.

And I can get the FTP directory detail like

```
04-17-15  07:21PM                    2 a.txt
```

This is my way to get file name or folder name:

```
        #region 得到文件夹的名称
        public string GetFolderNameByFTPDirectoryDetail(string FTPDirectoryDetails)
        {
            string folderName = "";            
            logger.Info("文件的详细路径为："+FTPDirectoryDetails);
            string[] folderNameArr = FTPDirectoryDetails.Split(new string[] { "  "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int arrLength = folderNameArr.Length;
            folderName = folderNameArr[arrLength-1];
            logger.Info("获取FTP文件夹的名称为：" + folderName);
            return folderName;
        }
        #endregion
```

And this function is so fragile because the folder name and filename could contain ' '.

How do I get the filename and folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  /// <summary>
/// 从ftp服务器上获得文件夹列表
/// </summary>
/// <param name="RequedstPath">服务器下的相对路径</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<string> GetDirctory(string RequedstPath)
{
    List<string> strs = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        string uri = path + RequedstPath;   //目标路径 path为服务器地址
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        // ftp用户名和密码
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());//中文文件名

        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("<DIR>"))
            {
                string msg = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf("<DIR>")+5).Trim();
                strs.Add(msg);
            }
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        return strs;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("获取目录出错：" + ex.Message);
    }
    return strs;
}
```

You can reference:[http://www.cnblogs.com/zhangjun1130/archive/2010/03/24/1693932.html](http:////www.cnblogs.com/zhangjun1130/archive/2010/03/24/1693932.html)